# Subsetting a vector with variables changes the length of the result vector

Tags: r, vector, subset

I want to subset a vector called `text` using variables for the slicing points. The problem is that the resulting vector has the same length as the input vector and the last 10 elements are NA. What is the reason of this?

```
> data_starts_at+1
[1] 11
> length(text)
[1] 12335
> x = text[11:12335]
> length(x)
[1] 12325
> x = text[data_starts_at+1:length(text)]
> length(x)
[1] 12335
> tail(x)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

**Update:**

It looks like this problem is related to operator precedence:

```
> x = text[(data_starts_at+1):length(text)]
> length(x)
[1] 12325
```

But using `x = text[data_starts_at+1:length(text)]` makes subsetting correctly except that there are additional 10 elements appended at the end of `x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is a probelm of parenthesis

```
x <- 1:10
data_starts_at <- 2
data_starts_at+1:10
[1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
# it means that you add data_starts_at at the vector 1:10
# then the final NA is because you ask for data that does not exist (11 & 12)
x[(data_starts_at+1):10]
[1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 #it's ok
```

hth

Answer (score 1):

Use correct parentheses:

```
x = text[(data_starts_at+1):length(text)]
```

What you were doing is to take indices `1:length(text)` and add `data_starts_at` to each of these values.